# Where is tree grammars in ANTLR4?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I'm going to migrate from ANTLR3 to ANTLR4, I appreciated auto-left recursion resolving, but..I did not found tree grammars, -> instructions supported.

Could anyone explain what is the reason of removing of this feature and what would I do?

If I understood right, I need to write a java node listener. Is there a guidline for migration from 3 to 4 like [this](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Migrating+from+ANTLR+2+to+ANTLR+3)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen these links?

https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1900596

Also a discussion on this topic. Google search found both on first page, top 3

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/antlr-discussion/W9zGVdd6BKQ